# How to run app as jar in IDE, but package with maven as war?

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, spring-boot

I have an application with a normal main method, running as a normal `jar` within my IDE. It's a `spring-boot` application that runs on an embedded tomcat by default.

To package it as `war` file with `maven` is as simple as:

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
    ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Problem: I'd still would like to run the app locally in my IDE embedded. Thus exclude the dependency above, and leave packaging to `>jar<`.

Question: is it possible to eg define profiles in maven, so that by default the packaging is =jar, but when running a specific profile it is exchanged with `war` and the tomcat server dependency is included?

Comment: Yes. There's an option "profile" in Eclipse (if that's what you're using). I'll check the path and answer the question.

Comment: You don't need to package it as a `jar` to be runnable. You can also run the war, next to that you still have the main method ...

Comment: @M.Deinum That would be great, but if I change the packaging to `war`, I'm getting the following exception: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/Filter`, no matter if I add or exclude the dependency statement for starter-tomcat above.

Comment: Which is actually due to Intellij which doesn't add `provided` dependencies to the class path. When using `mvn springBoot:run` it will work. You don't want to work with different artifacts/build for different environments eventually that will bite you. (So if you use a tomcat in production to deploy to imho you should also do that locally, in this case especially due to different loading rules for resources).

Comment: OK I see, thanks. But I'd like to keep running the app just clicking run from the gui, without maven. So I'd probably have to stick to the profile approach below.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, it's as simple as:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>development</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <packaging.type>jar</packaging.type>
        </properties>
    </profile>

    <profile>
        <id>production</id>
        <properties>
            <packaging.type>war</packaging.type>
        </properties>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

+for IntelliJ IDEA: running the appropriate maven command is as simple as: checking the desired profile an click on 'package'.